# Can I prevent a CK Editor instance from being created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm working on a markdown plugin for a CMS that uses CK Editor. I need to disable CK Editor so that it doesn't interfere with the markdown.

Is there a way, through Javascript, to prevent a CK Editor instance from being created?

The instance is being created with the [CK Editor for jQuery](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) adapter, the code is as follows:

```
jQuery('#summary').ckeditor(
    { 
        toolbar:'Summary',
        customConfig : 'config.js.cfm'
    },
    htmlEditorOnComplete
);
```

I understand that I can destroy an instance by listening for the `instanceReady` event like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e){
    e.editor.destroy();
});
```

That's not suitable for my needs because I need to target specific CK Editor instances(there are multiple that can exist in this area and I don't want to disable them all) and because I would like to stop CK Editor *before* it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you can try:

```
$('#summary').bind('instanceReady.ckeditor', function(e, editorInstance){
     editorInstance.destroy();
});
```

This is based on the info in the events handling section of the link you provided for the jQuery adaptor.

Comment: @s992 See my updated code. The first argument should be the event. I just tested this and it appears to work.

Comment: Almost there, `CKEditor not yet initialized, use ckeditor() with callback.`.

Comment: I should clarify - this is actually working, but it's still throwing an exception. Any idea why?

Comment: @s992 I would have to see your code to be sure. How are you initializing ckeditor? I'm using $('#summary').ckeditor(function () {}, config), where config is my configuration object...

Comment: The code that initializes CK Editor is in the original question, it's the first code block. :)

Comment: @s992 I guess I'm saying I would need to see more of the code - in context. Looking at the source of the jQuery adapter it seems that error is only thrown if you try to call a ckeditor function before the instance has finished initializing (before the instanceReady event). The only scenario that I could think of this happening is if you attempt to initialize ckeditor more than once on the same element in rapid succession, but without seeing the code I'm just guessing...

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept because your answer does work and the exception being thrown doesn't seem to be breaking anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on instanceReady to destroy specific elements

```
$('#summary').on('instanceReady', function(e){
  destroy(e);
});
```